# Out/In animation on same element in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-animatable

I have a `TextView` which will `fadeOutDown` the old data and `fadeInDown` the new data on the next render. How do I accomplish this? I am using the `react-native-animatable` library and have managed to do one animation but don't know how to do two.

```
<Animatable.View animation={this.props.animation} style = {styles.innerView2}>
  <Text text = "abcd" style = {{alignItems: 'flex-start', width: DEVICE_WIDTH - 20, textAlign: 'left'}}/>
</Animatable.View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a `ref` to the Animatable component and then for example on `componentDidUpdate`, you can re-trigger the animation

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.view !== undefined && this.view !== null) {
    this.view.fadeIn(1000);
  }
}

<Animatable.View
  ref={ref => (this.view = ref)}
  animation="fadeIn"
  easing="ease-in">
  <Text>{this.state.newText}</Text>
</Animatable.View>
```

Here's a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@syahrul/animatable-re-render) for your reference

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue. i want that the component will fade out the old data and fade in the new one.  Since `react-native-animatable` is declarable, how do I ddo this?

Comment: that is just for guidance, you can change the this.view.fadeOut or this.view.fadeIn upon retrieving the data to simulate the fadeOut fadeIn effect

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it did.

Comment: But which lifecycle method should I use for the fadeOut and the fadeIn?

Comment: it doesn't have to be a lifecycle method, whenever you want to animate the animatable component, that's how you do it

Comment: The text will fadeOut and the new text will fadeIn. I don't know when to do the fadeOut in this case.

Comment: that would depend on your app, are you fetching a data? maybe before you fetch you can fadeOut the component

Comment: No, the data is already fetched. I am just replacing the data on a swipe up and swipe down.

Comment: maybe you can use setTimeout then to fadeOut and fadeIn the component